# npm error when installing grunt/latest versions

Tags: android, node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

When upgrading **npm** to **latest version** or installing **grunt** using command prompt, I'm getting the following exception.

```
C:\Users\username>npm install npm@latest
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 103.245.222.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\username\npm-debug.log
```

I tried the following commands to install latest version of npm

```
npm install npm@latest
```

And for installing grunt

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

For both, I'm getting the above error. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

**Update:**

I tried the following. I have configured the proxy address and then tried to install grunt.

For HTTP:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
```

For HTTPS:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

But, it still showing the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS NPM Proxy error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989401/nodejs-npm-proxy-error)

Comment: @MukeshSharma: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

This one resolved me an issue.

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

And then, installed grunt and it worked!