# npm is showing errors while installing pacakages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, npm-install

[Please view the errors in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBmXq.jpg)
I am new to web-development and while learning react.js and installing lite-server I faced this problem. Please help me rectify it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS NPM Proxy error when installing grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989401/nodejs-npm-proxy-error-when-installing-grunt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes:

1.Run these three commands:

````
npm config set proxy http://localhost:8080/
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8080/
npm config set strict-ssl false```
````

It would point to localhost:8080 and would configure it with the module.

For more info visit https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config
Once the above changes are done, run the following command:

2. Now Run the following command:
   `npm config edit`

This will show the three statements which are entered above, you just need to remove it
and save & close all windows and start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:8080
```